# Elastic Search Filter Combination

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Our Problem is that we have some similar entries multiple times and want to only count them once.

Table:
`car name|inserted_by_user|insert_date
Audi A7|0123|22.01.2016
Audi A7|0290|24.01.2016 
Audi A7|0290|24.01.2016 
BMW M2|0290|25.01.2016 
Audi A7|0290|29.01.2016`

I would like to get ->

Audi A7: 1
BMW M2: 1

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use terms aggregation. In your case it would look like this:

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
       "car_names" : {
           "terms" : { "field" : "car_name" }
        }
    }
}
```

The response should be in the following pattern:

```
...
"aggregations" : {
    "car_names" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
        "buckets" : [ 
            {
                "key" : "Audi A7",
                "doc_count" : 6
            },
            {
                "key" : "BMW M2",
                "doc_count" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats wrong, I need to get back Audi A7 1 not 6 (I would like to count all Audi A7 as one result). You have any solutions ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no query in ES that would do that. doc_count will always be returned. Why is that a problem for you? Just simply do not use that field.